# ASP.NET Website doesn't recognize css files called in a div

Tags: css, html

I have encountered a very strange issue.

As I was reconstruction my login page using `div`s instead of a `table`, I obviously added an `id` to each `div` to call it from `css`.

Here's some **HTML CODE** as an example:

```
<div id="divLogin">
    <div id="divLblLogin"><asp:Label ID="lblLogin" runat="server">LOGIN</asp:Label>        
    </div>
</div>
```

and some **CSS CODE:**

```
#divLogin
{
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 28%;
    margin-right: 28%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    font-family: Good Times;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

#divLblLogin
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

The thing is that when I run the website from visual studio (local host) it appears to be normal and according to what I have defined (graphically).

But when I **publish** the website, and run it on the web, it shows only the controls without all the stylings (as if there is no css code at all)

So I decided to write all the css inside the `div` itself as:

```
<div 
        style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 28%; margin-right: 28%; height: 300px; border: 2px solid black;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        font-family: Good Times; font-size: xx-large;" 
>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 25px;"><asp:Label ID="lblLogin" runat="server">LOGIN</asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and that settled it, but I don't like this solution since its almost unreadable.

This is war, and I must win this thing whatever it is, **I.e. How to make the css work on the web without defining the style inside the div itself???**

Help will be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Here is my MasterPage having the css references and the files & foldes hierarchy in the solution explorer

[image: Folder Hierarchy and css reference in MasterPage:]

Comment: As you're styling a class, you need to use the dot notation in your CSS - ie `.divLogin {` - as the hash notation is for selecting by ID..

Comment: My bad, it actually is `id` and not a `class`. Posted wrong code accidentally. Updated!

Comment: In that case, how are you referencing the CSS, is in inline in the file or in a file? If it's in a file, is the file being published correctly?

Comment: Not quiet sure I understood the question, but I've added an image that might clarify things a bit.
I know that it is published correctly since basically, css is readable and working on the rest of my pages. It fails only when I call a css in a div like above `<div id="SomeDivID">` and `#SomeDivID { // some css code }`

Comment: ohh now I understood, it's in a css file, and the file is referenced in the masterpage (see edited image above)

Answer (score 5):

In the style sheet use class selector `.divLogin` instead of your ID selector `#divLogin`.

See [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for reference.

Comment: My bad, it actually is `id` and not a `class`. Posted wrong code accidentally. Upadated!

Comment: Have you checked the CSS file has correct path? Inspect HTML code, or check with Fiddle..

Comment: I have posted an image of the css references in the master page, and you can find in the solution explorer the folders hierarchy. As far as I know, the file paths are correct since other css functions are working.

Comment: That looks fine, but I would start from the other end, checking what is rendered in browser. I recommend using Google Chrome, e.g. right clicking on your div and choosing Inspect Element can help you identify what styles are being applied.

Comment: Your browser can be blocking the access to the site resources.

I suggest you click to show the page source, then grab a url from a javascript or css file from your source and paste it on the browser.

It is probably going to ask if you're sure that you want to load it. Choose yes to permit and then reload your page.

Comment: I put this issue on hold in my project since I had found another solution less elegant and yet effective. But I'll look into it. Thank you.